# `map` performing N+1 queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my code, I have a selection that includes:

```
nodes_list =
  Foo
  .where(id: foo_ids)
  .includes(node: [:nodes, node_image, :parent_node])
  .includes(:bar, :foo_image)
  .flat_map {|foo| [foo.node, foo.node.parent_node]}.uniq.compact
```

This part works fine and avoids N+1 queries as expected. However, later in my code, I have this:

```
nodes_list.map do |node|
  if node.nodes.empty?
    image = node.foo.foo_image
  else
    image = node.node_image
  end

  {
    id: node.id,
    name: node.name,
    image: image,
    parent_id: node.parent_node,
  }
end
```

In this case, I have N+1 queries on `parent_node`, `nodes` and `node_image`, which should be in my `includes`. How can I avoid those N+1 queries?

Comment: Read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

Comment: @ArupRakshit : already read, but I don't see where my mistake is.

Comment: Why do you have this: `flat_map {|foo| [foo.node, foo.node.parent_node]}.uniq.compact`. Seems to me that it might cause extra complexity and possibly introduce the `N + 1` queries

Comment: @Albin : because I need to get a list of nodes, and not foos.
My structure is as follows :
nodes can have multiple nodes,
nodes can have one parent_node,
nodes can have one foo,
foos can have one node

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the reason you are seeing these `N + 1` queries is that you are not including anything in the `parent_node` I think it can be avoided if you write it like this:

```
nodes_list =
  Foo
  .where(id: foo_ids)
  .includes(node: [:nodes, :node_image, parent_node: [:nodes, :node_image, :parent_node]])
  .includes(:bar, :foo_image)
  .flat_map {|foo| [foo.node, foo.node.parent_node]}.uniq.compact
```

**Completely separate from the question I would like to add the following:**

You could remove the `includes(:bar, :foo_image)` since that will only cause extra work. The `foos` you fetch and decorate with `bar` and `foo_image` are discarded without using these prefetched decorations.